# how to use a converter inside a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, staticresource

I have a converter thats works great when I use it as StaticResource on my Window as follows

```
<UserControl.Resources>
           <local:ValidationErrorConverter x:Key="validationErrorConverter"/>       
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I have a ResourceDictionary that defines my controls ControlTemplates and Styles , I couldn't figure out where to reference my converter as a StaticResource to be able to use it on my styles as follows

```
<Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem, 
Converter={StaticResource HERE??}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just create a new one, if the converter is needed for a Style just use `Style.Resources` for it. Or you could use element syntax:

```
<Setter.Value>
    <Binding Path="(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem"
             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
        <Binding.Converter>
            <local:ValidationErrorConverter />
       </Binding.Converter>
    </Binding>
</Setter.Value>
```

Comment: yes but I have to do it then on every control style , I want to set it once and apply to all controls , if I have to repeat them o the ResourceDictionary, I could just do it as I stated on the code that in my question post

Comment: @Musaab: If you place something in the `Application.Resources` in the `App.xaml` you can reference it from everywhere using StaticResource, maybe that helps, not quite sure what you mean...

Comment: I'm placing the ResourceDictionary in my App.Resources,to act as my DynamicResource. if I place <local:ValidationErrorConverter x:Key="validationErrorConverter"/> also inside App.Resources an Exception occured,  I will edit my question to better explain it

Comment: Thanks I found what I'm looking for, usine element syntax